# How to drop a column based on its title value?

Tags: python

I'm trying to drop columns based on its column title. I'd like to use a for loop and if conditions. Date range is from 1850 to 2100. below is a sample of my dataframe df

```
Indicator Code  1970    1971    1972    1973    1974    1975    1976    1977    1978    1979    1980    
DTFTS             x      x        x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x      
DTHUYZ            x      x        x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x       
YHTS              x      x        x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x       x
```

I would like to keep columns for instance from 1980 to 1990 using for and if. this is what I tried but its doesn't work:

```
columns_to_keep = list(range(1980,1990))

for columns in df :
  if df[~df.columns.isin(columns_to_keep)] :
      df.drop(columns)
```

Any piece of advice to help me please?

Thx!

Comment: when you use `drop`  to remove columns you need to use the flag `axis=1` and `inplace=True`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me know if this code works:

```
columns_to_keep = list(range(1980,1990))

for column in df.columns:
    if int(column) not in columns_to_keep:
        df.drop(column,axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Comment: Try now. I added the code. the problem was that we compare string(column name) between an integer.